# Reflection in TDD

Tags: tdd

I have read in a number of places that using reflection to set internal fields during TDD is bad as it probably implies that we have not yet sorted our interface for the Class under test. However I would like to present a scenario which i think is perfectly plausible and I cannot think of any clean solution to the problem at hand except Reflection.

Here is an example class with a corresponding test:

```
public Class Movie
{
   public string MovieName{get; private set}

   public void AddExternalReview(IMovieReview review)
  {
      //Logic that needs Unit testing.
      if ( review.MovieName.Equals(MovieName) )
      {
         //Do stuff..
      }
  } 
}
```

UnitTest:

```
[Test]
public Class MovieTests
{
   public void CanAddExternalReview()
   {
      MovieReviewStub movieReviewStub = new MovieReviewStub(); 
      movieReviewStub.MovieName = "The Godfather";

      Movie m = new Movie();
      //Need to Set object m state(i.e set Property MovieName to "The Godfather")
      //Only way to do that seems to be relection.

      m.AddExternalReview(movieReviewStub);
      //Assert on some condition.
   }
}
```

It is quite common to have properties that cannot be set by a Class's "normal" Clients. However the UnitTest Class may need access to such Properties/Fields so that it can set the relevant state necessary for the Test. As far as I can see reflection is the only way out. 
This must be quite a common requirement, yet most articles/discussions on the web seem to frown upon the use of reflection in TDD. Any ideas/insights would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the logic being tested has a dependency that's not being fulfilled.  There's a pre-condition to the test that isn't being satisfied, and that pre-condition is what sets the value.

There's no clean way in the code to set the value manually without using reflection.  So why test something that logically won't happen in the code?  (Unless the code is also using reflection to set the value.  In which case there's *definitely* an abstraction problem with the class.)

If the class is protecting that setter for a reason, work within the bounds of that protection.  Otherwise, as you say, the interface isn't properly sorted out.  Whatever logical process sets that value is a precondition of the test.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the prompt reply. You are right, the logic being tested does have a pre-condition which is that the MovieName for the entity has already been set by some other piece of logic in the distant past( In the entity's life cycle). That logic too also been unit tested and is fine. My requirement is that the 2 pieces of logic need to be tested independently, which I understand is the right way to unit test.

Comment: @rhk98: In general, yes, that's the right way to unit test.  So this may require a deeper look at that "logic in the distant past."  It sounds like that logic needs to be provided to the test or perhaps mocked in some way.  Without more information about that logic, I can't really be more specific.  This is likely one of those cases where you need to look at the return on investment for doing it "the clean way."  Using reflection "works" and may be "good enough" in this case, it's just a matter of how much "the clean way" is worth to you.

Comment: Sorry,when I meant the entity's life cycle I did not mean the development lifecycle but the lifecycle of the Movie object after it has been created. After creation, some logic added the Movie Name(not by reflection but a separate method). The entity then got persisted. Some Other Client later retrieves the persisted entity( with MovieName set) and wants to add a review. The concept I am trying to get at is that an object's behaviour can depend on state that is not modifiable as per the Class's interface. Yet that behaviour needs to be unit tested.

Comment: @rhk98: If this logic being tested happens after the entity has been persisted then achieving the testable state should be simple without reflection.  The creation of the object for the test should be done with a mock data access.  In this case, the dependency we were looking for was where you said "retrieves the persisted entity (with MovieName set)."  Mock that for the test.  That's the pre-condition the test needs.

Comment: I would suggest that if you really need that property to be privately set - either make it initialize from the constructor, or make it's producer class an interface, and create a test double for that so that you can produce testable movies in your unit tests. Resorting to reflection to unit test is usually a sign that things are starting head in a less than optimal direction.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence that puzzles me in your problem description is "It is quite common to have properties that cannot be set by a Class's "normal" Clients." This sounds like you have two (or more) types of clients for your class. If that's the case your different types of clients should see different interfaces. The implementation class however is the same and should not hide the property's setter; writing the test is simple then.

I guess it all boils down to a question of design priorities. When doing TDD I usually favor testability over data hiding and encapsulation. To prioritize the other way round will sometimes make testing hard and non-intuitive - as in your example.

Comment: By "normal" clients I meant the real clients ( other Classes) in the domain. If these clients try an operation that is invalid then that obviously results in an exception. e.g. in my example if a Client called AddExternalReview() just after a new Movie object was created, that should result in an exception. However as far as unit testing just the logic in AddExternalReview is considered, that is a perfectly acceptable scenario.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about encapsulation vs testability, but I don't feel comfortable with the idea. To me it sounds like leakage of testing concerns into the domain model. I am not comfortable with getter and setter confetti in my domain classes just because it makes unit testing simpler. I would rather stay true to OOP principles in my Domain model and pay the ( in my opinion ) relatively minor cost of using reflection in my unit tests